# Как узнать с какого поисковика и по какому запросу был вход на сайте?

Tags: php

Частично решил, могу узнать с какого поисковика зашел пользователь на сайт, но не могу расшифровать запросы.

```
$R=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    echo "<br />Вы пришли с 1^".$R;

$A=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$U=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$R=urldecode ($R);

$S=iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251',$R );
echo "<br />Вы пришли с 2^".$S;
echo "Ваш IP - ".$A."<br>";
echo "Страница входа - ".$U."<br>";
if (strpos($S, "yandex") != 0) {
preg_match('"text=(.*?)[^&]*"', $S, $arr);
echo "Вы пришли с Яндекса по запросу ".$arr[1];
}
elseif (strpos($S, "google") != 0) {
preg_match('/q=(.*)&/sei', $S, $arr);
echo "Вы пришли с Google по запросу ".$arr[1];
}
elseif (strpos($S, "rambler") != 0) {
preg_match('"query=(.*?)[^&]*"', $S, $arr);
echo "Вы пришли с Rambler по запросу ".$arr[1];
}
else {echo "Вы пришли с ".$R;}
echo "<br />Вы пришли с ^^".$R;
echo "<br />Вы пришли с ^^".$R;
```

Все $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; закодированны

Вы пришли с ^^http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=420.IhHA6WhRucdPr1nWNyDHQ0siK4SFjHbq-J4wuD7oXf9W1FrcehISTYgeAZhE9RfUchllNR49ed5HuJ5rK_7NC-0A0lyvThdvjo18e26kzG6XGD7DmQ4sIGts5PMiBckA.9679c3486dc2e1ea3279d963a291ad9b222b526b&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9XsMCv5TMMN9UTQSQbnFqxRfmqMBQ4ByD1xpJTPeVDF2xVoxKc225k7FcJJ6ImKnAltOYXdnJEISosx2J-VYBhOavUSGvVqR7Qvx0nixxlBUnGDyVhvD5wpZiaCmUAijo7_QQGXrgMh2ozMbktTVYTkOfgCy1V1bZsYcnNca5Iy6ICyotzSx3OJyZlkmgnnndmA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxZ0d0Q2llanBvaWZ4MHU1YW1SSldOZ19LVXZZSjNHSDZqcVVxQmEya2NVZy01NXZUdVhxRTQ3VkNxYWU4cm5PdC1VM2N2T3N0all5Z2wxMXNYZVNHMmxPbTBXNlZHX0NzUQ&b64e=2&sign=175af98e2d2fb19a4ad29b0d8bcc408f&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1408360352550&mc=3.486972327955777

Answer (score 1):

Может попробовать воспользоваться бесплатными сервисами, такими как: metrika.yandex.ru ?

Comment: Яндекс.метрика нужна для мониторинга. А мне нужно чтобы на сайте выводился контент в соответствии с введенным запросом. При чем тут яндекс.метрика?

Comment: @Максим147, ХэшКод это не фриланс биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, уточните, что сделали сами, что не получилось.

Comment: все что выше - сделал сам. Получилось определить вот этот код который привел в конце (http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3By...). Как Вы видите понять, что переход был из "yandex" легко, но остальная строка это набор символов, по которому сложно что-либо сказать. 
В этом и вопрос, как его расшифровать?

Comment: На заметку: вроде, с гуглом будут проблемки, он использует https протокол)

Answer (score 1):

Прочитать запрос не получится Google и Yandex их теперь шифруют и не отдают. Посмотреть запросы возможно только поставив Google Analytics или Yandex Metrika.