# Узнать по какому поисковому запросу пришел пользователь (php, js), собрать доп.информацию

Tags: php, javascript, seo

Нужно для самописной crm узнать с какого поискового запроса пришел пользователь на сайт (использую javascript или php), а также другую дополнительную информацию.

смотрел и пробовал как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/354508/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5) . Понял что с $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] взять не получится, только адрес сайта откуда пришёл. 
Для индентификации adwords и директа можно использовать utm-метки, но это только маленькая часть трафика...

на сайте подключен гугл аналитика и яндекс метрика, возможно как-то из них можно вытянуть эту информацию? (в режиме реального времени).

Вообще каким способом и что можно узнать о пользователе, чтобы передать эту информацию в crm.

Comment: Мне кажется, что поисковики передают в refferer поисковый запрос в url через редирект.

Comment: Мне кажется, что поисковики перестали передавать в refferer поисковый запрос уже лет 10 назад

Comment: он там шифруется

Comment: вам этот запрос нужно на момент генерации страницы?

Comment: нет, можно после, я инфу могу на фронте обработать или передать по ajax

Comment: К примеру, в Яндекс.Вебмастер есть статистика поисковых запросов, CTR и т.д.
В Google.Webmaster тоже такая функция есть

Возможно, эта инфа будет тебе полезна)

Comment: но как мне оттуда её брать (в режиме реального времени) - мне нужно в црм сопоставлять данные о пользователе с его данными, которые он ввёл в форме на сайте

Comment: Увы, никак. Раньше давно еще с ****** можно было, но они тоже пожадничали.

Answer (score 1):

ПСы давно не передают поисковые запросы. А с принудительной https-зацией всё становиться ещё хуже. Так что с локальной аналитикой всё оч. плохо. Остаётся только "игла" от ПС - их аналитики/метрики.